# using wildcards in batch files in windows

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

Well, simple batch file question :

```
md "03 Explore\Music\Explore\"
move  * "03 Explore\Music\Explore"
```

works but moves also the bat !

```
move  *.mp3 "03 Explore\Music\Explore"
```

does not work.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and then in a couple of days accept it. You won't get any rep, but will help anyone else with the same problem coming along later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED :

```
move  *.mp3 "03 Explore\Music\Explore\"
```